# Replacing a "char" in StringBuilder string

Tags: java, char, stringbuilder

My requirement is pretty simple, fetch a char location and replace it with another.
Only catch is that, the `char` and its `index` comes at run time and can not be hard-coded.

Dummy code of my actual implementation :

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("just going nuts")  ;
   System.out.println(" "+sb);
   //System.out.println(sb.charAt(4)); //this works
   sb.setCharAt(sb.indexOf((sb.charAt(4))), sb.charAt(0)); //line 8 -error line
   System.out.println(" "+sb);
}
```

I even tried enclosing `char` in quotes :

```
sb.setCharAt(sb.indexOf(( "\""+sb.charAt(4)+"\"" )), sb.charAt(0));
```

but still same error

**Error**

```
line no:8: cannot find symbol
symbol : method indexOf(char)
location: class java.lang.StringBuilder
sb.setCharAt(sb.indexOf((sb.charAt(4))), sb.charAt(0));
```

I am not very fluent in Java but couldn't find `setCharAt` function examples having dynamic values like in this case!!

Comment: Off topic suggestion: `System.out.println(" "+sb);` could be `System.out.println(sb.toString());`

Comment: @Totò : thanks mate but i can not use it as the output is further processed!! :)

Comment: Your error talks of indexOf, not setCharAt

Comment: @Totò ... or just `System.out.println(sb)`

Comment: If you already know the index of the character you want to replace, why not use `sb.setCharAt(4, sb.charAt(0))` ?

Comment: u need to convert the `char` to string before calling indexOf

Comment: @KarthikT : yes and `setCharAt` is getting values from `indexOf` :)

Comment: and calling toString doesnt convert a object to string, it returns the stringified version of the object, i.e the original object is untouched and can still be used

Comment: @Stefan : i hard coded in this case, it actually under a `for-loop`!

Comment: **@downvoter :** dropping a message is always appreciated!! :)

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood : i do read...just was not able to understand where to look for solution!! :)

Comment: try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf  if you enter "Java className" into google usually the first page is the javadocs for this className

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is because `indexOf` is expecting a `String` not a `char` so all you have to do is wrap it with `String.valueOf`

```
sb.setCharAt(sb.indexOf(String.valueOf((sb.charAt(4)))), sb.charAt(0));
```

outputs

```
 just going nuts
 justjgoing nuts
```

Modern IDEs should catch this compile time error while you type even offer the solution (in the case below IntelliJ):

[image]

Comment: @dimitrisli : is there a way around without using `String` wrapper?

Comment: @NoobEditor if you are just using ascii, then cast as an int should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add null string

```
sb.setCharAt(sb.indexOf((sb.charAt(4))+""), sb.charAt(0));
```

As sb.indexOf() works with string not chatacters.